# Is it possible to learn homotopy theory from the perspective of HoTT?

Tags: soft-question, homotopy-theory, advice, learning, homotopy-type-theory

I'm more familiar with computer science than math. I watched [15-819](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/courses/hott/) and was able to understand most of the content , I think I can digest the HoTT (Homotopy Type Theory) book as well. However , now I want to learn some application of HoTT, i.e. homotopy theory. Is it possible without starting from scratch (set theory) currently?

Comment: Note that the tag     (homotopy-theory) is different from (homotopy-type-theory). You may remove the former to make the tags more accurate.

Comment: I know HoTT, and want to learn homotopy theory, maybe I have to be clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to learn classical homotopy theory (as it is done with topological spaces and simplicial sets), then knowing some HoTT will probably help your intuition in some ways (though it might also be dangerous in other ways), but I don't think it can help at the formal mathematical level.

Comment: How useful is HoTT itself then? I thought it can be an alternative foundation of math D:

Comment: It can.  Any mathematics you can define using set theory as a foundation, you can also define using HoTT as a foundation by interpreting sets as the "h-sets" defined inside HoTT.  This includes classical homotopy theory.  However, such a formulation doesn't generally provide any new insight into the mathematics in question or make it any easier to learn.  The real value of HoTT is that it also makes possible new kinds of mathematics that are not possible to formalize in set theory (at least, not directly), including "synthetic" homotopy theory.

Comment: Synthetic homotopy theory is analogous to classical homotopy theory, so intuition from one of them can help in learning the other.  But to make a *formal* connection between them requires already understanding both of them fairly well.